# VBA PivotTableWizard Object

Tags: vba, excel

I created a subroutine based off of the example VBA code on Microsoft's tutorial page: [LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh243933.aspx)

```
Sub WIP20Pivot()
'
' Pivot Macro

'Creates a PivotTable report from the table on Sheet1
'by using the PivotTableWizard method with the PivotFields
'method to specify the fields in the PivotTable.
 Dim objTable As PivotTable, objField As PivotField

' Select the sheet and first cell of the table that contains the data.
 ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("DATA").Select
 Range("A1").Select

' Create the PivotTable object based on the Employee data on Sheet1.
 Set objTable = Sheet1.PivotTableWizard 'ERROR OCCURS HERE
 ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotSheet" 

'There is more VBA code below to select fields for the pivot table, etc..

End Sub
```

And I receive the following error, when I run this code:

> Run-time error '424': "Object required".

What's strange is that the subroutine works perfectly fine in Microsoft's downloadable example macro on their tutorial page.

Thanks in advance for you help!

Thanks,
AME

Comment: If you do not have a pivot table  on the first sheet (by index) in your workbook, you will get that error. Change the sheet reference to suit your particular workbook and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Set objTable = Sheet1.PivotTableWizard 'ERROR OCCURS HERE

you have specified Shee1 however the real sheet name would have been different.
you would have deleted some sheets and may be you named the sheet as sheet1.
Please check in project window in vba editor your actual sheet name will be displayed like "Sheet9(Sheet1)". In this scenario you need to mention as

"Set objTable = Sheet9.PivotTableWizard"

thats it solved!!! :)

(Note your codes should be in Module)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. After I did some research, I found this solution. Hope it can also help you.

```
 Set objTable = Worksheets("PivotTable").PivotTableWizard(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Range("PivotData!A1:C3918"), tabledestination:=Range("PivotTable!A1"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Sub WIP20Pivot() => subroutine` must be in a module,

cannot be embedded in a worksheet.

It happen to me too.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this helps to name the Pivot sheet?